# Why does my asynchronous function work on Firefox, but it gives me an error on Chrome?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

So I have a function that gets a Shopping cart from firebase. It is an asynchronous function and it returns a promise>. The function works fine on Firefox and Edge but it breaks my application on Chrome. I get an error on the console. Anyone had a similar issue before?

Here is the error for Chrome

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot destructure property items of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at MapSubscriber.project (shopping-cart.service.ts:16)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at angularfire2.js:44
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
```

Here is my function

```
async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId).valueChanges()
    .pipe(map(({items}) => new ShoppingCart(items)));
  }
```

Here is shopping.cart.ts

```
import { Product } from './product';
import { ShoppingCartItem } from './shopping-cart-item';

export class ShoppingCart { 
  items: ShoppingCartItem[] = [];

constructor(private itemsMap: { [productId: string]: ShoppingCartItem }) {
    this.itemsMap = itemsMap || {};

    for (let productId in itemsMap) {
      let item = itemsMap[productId];
      this.items.push(new ShoppingCartItem({...item, key: productId})); 
    }
  }

  getQuantity(product: Product) {
    let item = this.itemsMap[product.key];
    return item ? item.quantity : 0;
  }

  get totalPrice() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let productId in this.items) 
      sum += this.items[productId].totalPrice;
    return sum;
  }

  get totalItemsCount() {
    let count = 0;
    for (let productId in this.itemsMap) 
      count += this.itemsMap[productId].quantity;
    return count;
  }
}
```

Here is shopping-cart-item.ts

```
    export class  ShoppingCartItem{
    key: string;
    title: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;

    constructor(init?: Partial<ShoppingCartItem>){
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }    
    get totalPrice(){
        return this.price * this.quantity;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying it can't destructure property items on an undefined or null object.  The only destructuring operation in the code you show is on this line:

```
this.items.push(new ShoppingCartItem({...item, key: productId}));
```

So I would guess that `item` is not what you expect.  I suggest starting your debugging there.

Comment: So I did `console.log(new ShoppingCartItem({...item, key: productId}));` and I get `Object { imageUrl: "http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/170000/velka/spinach-leaves-1461774375kTU.jpg", price: 2.5, quantity: 1, title: "Spinach", key: "-KrqgOLs07ZkbapP4EGi" } ` on the browser.